# (Java) couldn't find or load main class

Tags: java

I'm new in java and i need some help, i know there's a lot of threads about the same but i couldn't find how to solve this problem with the class.

To compilate

```
alpha@Alpha-:~$ javac ~/Escritorio/Test/EXAMPLE.java
```

**EXAMPLE.class** is in "Test" folder

When i try to run it

```
alpha@Alpha:~$ java -cp /~/Escritorio/Test EXAMPLE
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal EXAMPLE
(Error: couldn't find or load main class EXAMPLE)
```

I have Ubuntu 12.04.2

java and javac version 1.7.0_51

**EXAMPLE.java**

```
public class EXAMPLE
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     System.out.println("¡Mi primer programa!");
   }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a backslash: `alpha@Alpha:~$ java -cp /~/Escritorio/Test EXAMPLE`! Shouldn't that be, `alpha@Alpha:~$ java -cp /~/Escritorio/Test/EXAMPLE`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think you made a mistake did not you mean (s)he has an extra slash? `java -cp ~/Escritorio/Test EXAMPLE`

Comment: What package is it declared to be in?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you! It run, i can move forward in the guide now.

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
alpha@Alpha:~$ cd ~/Escritorio/Test
alpha@Alpha:~$ javac Example.java
alpha@Alpha:~$ java Example
```

Comment: It didnt work but the command is very useful, thank you for the help